# Looping through a multidimensional array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to use jQuery's **each** function to loop through the array below. My goal is to find both the key ("Name") and use its underlying array values to output in the webpage.

```
Array
(
    [E-mail] => Array
        (
            [0] => Your e-mail address is spelled incorrectly
            [1] => Another error just to annoy you further
        )
)
```

Comment: some thing is unclear how i write this in javascript?

Comment: So what's the problem? `$.each( array, function(key, value) {...`

Comment: Let me ask you a question: where is this array coming from? just curious.

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to mention that I am using jQuery's makeArray function to convert this string I received after my AJAX call. That's how I tried to convert it into an array... :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no associative arrays in Javscript, which means to get this :

```
Array
(
    [E-mail] => Array
        (
            [0] => Your e-mail address is spelled incorrectly
            [1] => Another error just to annoy you further
        )
)
```

You will not use an array, but an object instead, and then the object will contain an array of messages. Here is an example :

```
var data = {
   email : [
      "Your e-mail address is spelled incorrectly",
      "Another error just to annoy you further"
   ]
};
```

now, to loop arround your data.email array you can use `$.each` of jQuery or simply `Array.prototype.forEach` native method

```
data.email.forEach(function (item, index) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

using `$.each` :

```
$.each(data.email, function (index, item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didn't realize associative arrays don't exist in jQuery. My apologies. I think I will try to deliver the data in JSON, would that be better?

Comment: Yes, it would be better